# Is it possible to distinguish identical function calls in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I'm building a library and I want the library to be able to distinguish the different times when the user in his code calls the functions in my library. For example, if I have a function `sayHello()` defined like so:

```kotlin
fun sayHello() {
    when(idOfFunctionCall) {
        0 -> println("First call!")
        1 -> println("Second call!")
        else -> println("Some other call!")
    }
}
```

I want this function to be able to detect the different places in the user's code where this function was called.

```kotlin
// user's code
fun main() {
    sayHello()
    
    repeat(3) {
      sayHello()
    }
    
    sayHello()
}
```

This code should print:

```
First call!
Second call!
Second call!
Second call!
Some other call!
```

Is that even possible? I'm planning on using the Kotlin Reflection set of tools but I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Depending on the reason, there might be better ways than "getting the ID of the function call".

Comment: @Sweeper I'm creating a drawing library in Kotlin (inspired by Processing 3) in modern OpenGL (LWJGL3) and I basically want to save resources by creating a new vertex buffer in the GPU's memory every function call by the user. Basically, if the user writes `rect(0,0,100,100)` and after that `rect(200,200,0,0)` I want be able to distinguish these two and create two Rectangle objects (one for every function call). It's difficult to explain, please let me know if you didn't understand from my explanation.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't you want the code in the `repeat(3)` to be identified as different calls?

Comment: What you suggest seems like a very bad idea to me: fragile, slow, hard to test, and restrictive (for example, it'll fail badly if there are any calls with non-constant parameters).  As another comment says, this is an X-Y problem: it seems that what you really want to do is avoid allocating unnecessary vertex buffers… (contd)

Comment: I can see two approaches to saving memory here: 1) Have the caller allocate and pass in the vertex buffer; it can then use a static one where appropriate.  (Safe and efficient, but long-winded.)  Or 2) have a cache of previously-used buffers inside your function, and reuse one where possible.  (More work, but more flexible and simpler for the caller.)  There may be other approaches, too, depending on the exact problem.  Why not post another question with the actual details?

Comment: @Sweeper oh my god you are right... Sorry. I'm kinda lost in my ideas about the API I'm trying to make.

Comment: @gidds thank you very much for your extensive answer. I'll try to sum up my ideas and post another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the current thread's stack like this, hoping there are line numbers attached to all `StackTraceElement` instances:

```java
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

If line numbers aren't available, your `sayHello()` method could maintain some (probably quite expensive) `Map<MethodName, CallCount>` of some sort, and count the number of times a given client method calls your method. That will not produce the exact output you desired (e.g. if the call is in a loop). But it might do the trick.

Of course, this won't lead to anything reliable, but maybe, this is just about logging where inaccuracies and incomplete information might be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would need this to be 100% reliable and efficient. So this isn't an option then... I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: Well, there might be some wird solution to the question you've asked (e.g. using instrumentation), but it won't be a good or simple solution, nor will this lead to a good and easy to use API. You should not make any assumptions about your caller code and how they structure their 3 calls to your code. Ultimately, this is a case of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). I think you'll get a much better answer when you ask about how to best design the API given the requirements...